# side content bar material ui

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I'm interested in creating a content nav bar, similar to this one

[image]

This screenshot is taken from [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/)'s site, but I haven't been able to find a component inside the library that resembles it. Is there one? Is there a way repurpose either a [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) of an [App Bar](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/) to replicate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it’s always visible on the page that is just a normal div really.

Set it up in your  component (or wherever your routes are defined) so it is on every page